# Filtering dojo treegrid

Tags: dojo, filtering, treegrid

Is it possible to filer a dojo tree grid ?

Suppose if my tree has the following hierarchical data

a1
 ---b

```
 ---c
 ---d
```

--- e

I need to filter all the immediate children of a particular parent node and display it

```
 eg : if i give criteria as a1 - it should fetch me b and e 
      if i give criteria as b it should fetch c and d
```